# Can IIS 6 serve requests for pages with no extensions?

Tags: iis, iis-6

Is there any way in IIS to map requests to a particular URL with no extension to a given application.

For example, in trying to port something from a Java servlet, you might have a URL like this...

http://[server]/MyApp/HomePage?some=parameter

Ideally I'd like to be able to map everything under MyApp to a particular application, but failing that, any suggestions about how to achieve the same effect would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the IIS6 to handle all requests, but the key to handle files without extensions is to tell the IIS not to look for the file.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an ISAPI filter that re-writes urls.  The user enters a url with no extension, but the filter will interpret the request so that it does.  Note that in IIS it's real easy to screw this up, so you might want to find a pre-written one.  I haven't used any myself so I can't recommend a specific product that's any different than what you'd find via google, especially as I don't know your specific use case.  But at least now you know what to search for.

You can also rewrite your urls using ASP.Net:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx